# MySQL output being supressed in pipeline

Tags: mysql, github-actions

I am using a Github Actions pipeline and starting a mysql server using docker within that pipeline. I am attemtping to run a `show tables` command, however the output is being suppressed.

[image]

In the below pipeline i have a docker-compose file which runs a mysql server. Then i am attempting to connect to it and output the tables. However i never receive the output.

**pipeline.yml**

```
name: test-pipeline

on: [ push ]

jobs:
  test:
    name: Test Migration
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: '12'
    - name: Setup
      run: |
        docker-compose -f CI/docker-compose.yml up -d
        npm install
    - name: Check tables
      run: |
        mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --protocol=tcp --user=root --password=password testDB -e "show tables;"
        echo "here"
```

Comment: What happens when you run this locally? Is it possible that there are no tables and the output is empty? Have you tried replacing `show tables;` with something that's guaranteed to produce an output, such as `select 1`?

Comment: it worked locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else comes across this problem i  fixed it by not specifying the db upfront in the options, instead specifying the database in the -e command.

```
mysql --host=127.0.0.1 --protocol=tcp --user=root --password=password -e "show databases; use testDB; show tables;"
```